# Why containsAll does return true in second case

Tags: java, collections, set, contains

It compiles and runs without problems, but I cannot understand why second statement return false:

```
    String s0 ="0123";
    String s1 ="0123";


    System.out.println(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(s1.toCharArray()))).containsAll(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(s0.toCharArray()))));
    System.out.println(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.toCharArray())).containsAll(Arrays.asList(s0.toCharArray())));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

JDK 1.8

EDIT:

Thank you @Eran
There is a compilation problem  when I avoid diamond operator like this:

```
new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(s1.toCharArray())).containsAll(Arrays.asList(s0.toCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `s0.toCharArray()` is a primitive array (`char[]`), `Arrays.asList(s0.toCharArray())` is a List whose single element is a `char[]`. 
Similarly, `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s1.toCharArray()))` is a Set that contains a single `char[]`.

Those two `char[]` objects are not equal, since arrays don't override `Object`'s `equals` and each call to `toCharArray[]` creates a new array isntance, so even if `s0==s1`, `s0.toCharArray() != s1.toCharArray()` and `s0.toCharArray().equals(s1.toCharArray())` is false.

In your first line of code, I'm assuming that `ArrayUtils.toObject` converts the primitive array to a reference array (i.e. from `char[]` to `Character[]`), which is why `containsAll` returns true (since both the `HashSet` and the `List` contain 4 `Character` instances, and the `Character` class overrides `equals`, so all the `Character`s in the `List` are contained in the `HashSet`).

Comment: Eran, you're right with your assumption. `ArrayUtils` has a `toObject` implementation for each primitive array type: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html